# factor name has new levels while using predict function in test data set

Tags: r, decision-tree, predict

I'm trying to solve the titanic data set from kaggle.
I have done almost all the work on train data set 
train (891 obs of 12 variables)
test (418 obs of 11 variables)

I have used decision trees (rpart method)

confusionMatrix(pred_train,train$Survived)
Confusion Matrix and Statistics

```
              Reference
    Prediction   0   1
             0 549   0
             1   0 342

               Accuracy : 1                  
                 95% CI : (0.996, 1)         
    No Information Rate : 0.616              
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : <0.0000000000000002

                  Kappa : 1                  
 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : NA                 

            Sensitivity : 1.000              
            Specificity : 1.000              
         Pos Pred Value : 1.000              
         Neg Pred Value : 1.000              
             Prevalence : 0.616              
         Detection Rate : 0.616              
   Detection Prevalence : 0.616              
      Balanced Accuracy : 1.000              

       'Positive' Class : 0
```

I use `pred <- predict (fit ,test ,type = "class")` I get

> Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action,
>   xlev = attr(object,  :    factor Name has new levels Abbott, Master.
>   E...

how can I solve this problem as there is difference in observations of train and test data set (891 and 418) and I have already removed identifier(passengerId) from train data set

Answer (score 0):

before training you need to `rbind` test and train then use factor and extract "new" train and test with all factor levels

Comment: you mean to say before applying decision trees or from very beginning ( even before feature engineering )

Comment: yes at the beginning if there s unknowwn factor in test data predict fail

Comment: x <- cbind(x_train,y_train)
     # grow tree 
     fit <- rpart(y_train ~ ., data = x,method="class")
     summary(fit)
     #Predict Output 
     predicted= predict(fit,x_test)     where y_train = train$survived , x_train = train, x_test = test                                                               
 error i gt                                                                              Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'Survived' not found

Comment: `rbind` not `cbind` check some kernel on the kaggle forum https://www.kaggle.com/mrisdal/exploring-survival-on-the-titanic